# Spring Boot Websocket with SockJS and StompJS connect function does not work, always error

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I try to build a chat application with HTML,JS,CSS with the libraries STOMPJS and SOCKJS as the frontend and Spring Boot as backend.

My connect code in the frontend looks like this:

```
 function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/chat");
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

        stompClient.connect(
          {},
          function (frame) {
            console.log("2");

            setConnected(true);
            console.log("Connected: " + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe("/topic/messages", function (messageOutput) {
              showMessageOutput(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
            });
          },
          console.log("error")
        );
      }
```

As far as I know is the connect function of STOMPJS like this: headers, connectCallback, errorCallback.

It never reach the console.log "2" and it gives me the console.log "error" back.

I activated CORS like this in my backend with setAllowedOriginPatterns("*") in my Spring Boot application:

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
         registry.addEndpoint("/chat");
         registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class MController {
    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public OutputMessage send(Message message) throws Exception {
        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
        return new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText(), time);
    }
}
```

In the screenshot you can see the console.log when I execute the function "connect":

[image]

I checked all the documentation of SockJS and StompJS but I couldn't find a solution.

Thank you very much for your answer in advance. :)

Comment: _"The message port closed before a response was received"_ - Sounds like the server threw an exception and closed the connection. Look at the server error logs for more information.